# Unable to create database because it's already exists, but it doesn't

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I want to create hive database using the command:

```
create database sbx_products_diff
```

But it fails with the following error:

> jdbc:hive2://myhost> create database sbx_products_diff;
>
> INFO  : Compiling
> command(queryId=hive_20220414115555_9db94201-d1b7-40ca-8cee-d1d4147c080e):
> create database sbx_products_diff INFO  : Semantic Analysis
> Completed INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null,
> properties:null) INFO  : Completed compiling
> command(queryId=hive_20220414115555_9db94201-d1b7-40ca-8cee-d1d4147c080e);
> Time taken: 0.003 seconds INFO  : Executing
> command(queryId=hive_20220414115555_9db94201-d1b7-40ca-8cee-d1d4147c080e):
> create database sbx_products_diff INFO  : Starting task
> [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return
> code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Database
> sbx_products_diff already exists INFO  : Completed
> executing
> command(queryId=hive_20220414115555_9db94201-d1b7-40ca-8cee-d1d4147c080e);
> Time taken: 0.014 seconds Error: Error while processing statement:
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Database
> sbx_products_diff already exists (state=42000,code=1)

But the problem is that this database doesn't exists actually:

> jdbc:hive2://myhost> drop database sbx_products_diff;
>
> Error: Error while compiling statement:
> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist:
> sbx_products_diff (state=42000,code=10072)

Seems like this problem is related to this database particularly, because if I run exactly the same command, but with another name it works perfectly, as expected. Could someone make a direction what is the root of my troubles? Or what should I share to let you help me?

UPD1:

> If you look in the hive warehouse folder, do you see a folder called "sbx_products_diff"?

No, the directory doesn't exist. But I should tell another thing, that is interesting. `_diff` part of the name is suffix. I mean there are several existing databases - `sbx_products`, `sbx_products_aux`, `sbx_products_bkp`, .. And all of those databases located in hdfs with the following structure:

> - hdfs://bla-bla/sbx_products/hive/pa
> - hdfs://bla-bla/sbx_products/hive/aux
> - hdfs://bla-bla/sbx_products/hive/bkp
> - ...

Also, I have already searched my database with commands like:

- hdfs dfs -ls -R / | grep diff
- hdfs dfs -ls -R / | grep sbx_products

But nothing related to my ghost database were found.

Comment: Do you have any hive logs related to this error? (Not just the console output)

Comment: If you look in the hive warehouse folder, do you see a folder called "sbx_products_diff"?

Comment: @MattAndruff Updated post with hdfs information. And searching for hive logs now

Comment: @MattAndruff Unfortunately, I have no enough permissions to see logs. Corporate settings, OMG! Of course, I will try to request access, but it will take a time. Thank you, anyway, for your time

Comment: Seems like you found the issue. Can you make a table urmat_diff?

Comment: You can try validating this by searching Jira for Hive & Github for hive. looking for issues around '_diff' or open an issue for this...
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9130?jql=project%20%3D%20HIVE%20AND%20text%20~%20_diff

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hive/search?q=diff